# Add new column into nested BigQuery STRUCT (for new `bi_engine_reasons` column in the `query_info` STRUCT from the new INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS schema)

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, information-schema

We store historic data from the BigQuery `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS` in order to be able to analyse historic jobs for longer than the 6 months after which BigQuery deletes them.

However on `2024-01-16` the schema changed, adding an additional field `bi_engine_reasons` into the `query_info` STRUCT at the column path `query_info.performance_insights.stage_performance_standalone_insights.bi_engine_reasons` and causing the insert job to fail due to schema mismatch.

After a huge amount of trial and error, I finally managed to manually construct a SQL query which adds a NULL version of this ARRAY in the correct position, however it was extremely laborious and time-consuming to identify and implement.  It is also verbose and not reusable.

Is there a better way to achieve this in a cleaner, more concise and reusable manner?

Posting my (ugly) solution here, it's not pretty but it does work.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `[NEW_SCHEMA_TABLE_ID]`
PARTITION BY DATE(creation_time)
AS 
WITH
get_historic_data AS (
SELECT *
FROM `[OLD_SCHEMA_TABLE_ID]`
),

replace_query_info AS (
SELECT 
creation_time,
project_id,
project_number,
user_email,
job_id,
job_type,
statement_type,
priority,
start_time,
end_time,
query,
state,
reservation_id,
total_bytes_processed,
total_slot_ms,
error_result,
cache_hit,
destination_table,
referenced_tables,
labels,
timeline,
job_stages,
total_bytes_billed,
transaction_id,
parent_job_id,
session_info,
dml_statistics,
total_modified_partitions,
bi_engine_statistics,

--query_info
STRUCT ( 
  query_info.resource_warning,
  query_info.optimization_details,
  --query_hashes
  STRUCT (
    query_info.query_hashes.normalized_literals
    ) AS query_hashes,
  --performance_insights
  STRUCT (
  query_info.performance_insights.avg_previous_execution_ms,
    --stage_performance_standalone_insights
    ARRAY( SELECT AS STRUCT
      stage_performance_standalone_insight.stage_id AS stage_id,
      stage_performance_standalone_insight.slot_contention,
      stage_performance_standalone_insight.insufficient_shuffle_quota,
        --bi_engine_reasons
        ARRAY (SELECT AS STRUCT
        CAST(NULL AS STRING) AS code,
        CAST(NULL AS STRING) AS message
        ) AS bi_engine_reasons
    ) AS stage_performance_standalone_insights,
    --stage_performance_change_insights
    ARRAY( SELECT AS STRUCT
      stage_performance_change_insight.stage_id AS stage_id,
      STRUCT(stage_performance_change_insight.input_data_change.records_read_diff_percentage) AS input_data_change
    ) AS stage_performance_change_insights
  ) AS performance_insights
) AS query_info,

  transferred_bytes,
  materialized_view_statistics

FROM get_historic_data
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(query_info.performance_insights.stage_performance_standalone_insights) AS stage_performance_standalone_insight
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(query_info.performance_insights.stage_performance_change_insights) AS stage_performance_change_insight
)

SELECT *
FROM replace_query_info
```